# Jquery add month to selected date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

We have 1 Month, 3 Month, 6 Month,  9 Months, 1 Year Membership in dropdown list

What we where trying to do is if user select 25/06/2012 for start of membership of 9 months, we want to show him when his membership will expire like say 25/03/2013. we tried many things but it give some wrong date.

we are using jquery-ui for selection of start membership date

Regards
Arshad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/), it's a little date library that's handy for this type of thing.

Comment: i'm using date.js for 3 years now. saves many hours of coding.

Answer (score 4):

```
 var date1 = new Date();
 date1 .setMonth(date1 .getMonth() - 12);
```

now date1 is an object holding a date which is 12 months ago

If you want to set it to the jQuery UI DatePickers, you can do this

```
    $("#txtToDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("setDate", date1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var s = $("#inputid");
var d= $.datepicker.parseDate(datepickeroption.dateFormat, s)
d.setMonth( d.getMonth( ) + 1 );
```